# struts2 call action from hyperlink with data

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have page where i display the list of employees, their names. I need to have them as hyperlinks ans on click of A employee name i need to call another action say "detailsAction". This action will get data about this employee from that DB and display the same in a page. How do i send the employee id associated with the hyperlink that the user clicked to my "detailsAction" ??

Right now the employee list is done below in my jsp page

```
<s:if test="empList">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
   </tr>
  <s:iterator value="empList">
  <tr>
     <td><s:property value="empName" /></td>
  </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
</s:if>
```

Comment: You add the ID as a parameter, like any other link.

Comment: like --> <td><a href="<s:url action="actionName"/>"> <s:property value="empName" id="empID"/></td> -- Is this correct??

Comment: @DaveNewton If the above is correct and i pass the id as shown... How do i access it in my action??

Comment: Same way as any other form value, via an action property. But it's not correct, did you actually try it? Did you try the answer?

Comment: @DaveNewton Nope that did not work.  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/empolyeeForm.jsp(31,44) Attribute id invalid for tag property according to TLD......... Any ideas??

Comment: Yes, I have some ideas: Read the documentation. Look at the answer below. What do you *think* it means when the JSP compiler is telling you that you're using an invalid attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Struts tags for that:

```
    <s:a href="/whateverAddress" >
        <s:text name="Link text goes here"/>
        <s:param name="param1" value="value1"/>    
    </s:a>
```

Comment: Useful Post...Thank You